# For the solvability of the poisson equation $\Delta u = f$ on manifold with boundary

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, parabolic-pde

For poisson equation $\Delta u = f$ in bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, we can directly get the solution by Green function. For poisson equation $\Delta u = f$ on closed Riemannian manifold, the necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of the solution is $\int_M f dV =0$.

What I want to ask is that for the Riemannian manifold with boundary, do we still have the Green function to directly have a solution for $\Delta u = f$. Can you share some lectures on this topic with me?

Maybe Theorem 4.8 in Thierry Aubin - Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry will help. It said that

let $\bar{W}_n$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary of then there exists a solution $\varphi \in C^{\infty}(\bar{W}_n)$  of
$$\Delta \varphi =f$$
here $f$ is smooth and $\varphi$ vanishes on the boundary.

But Thierry Aubin used variational method, is there any Green function related lectures?

Comment: I don't understand: if you found Aubin's book, why didn't you go to the immediate next page which starts the section titled "Green's function of the Laplacian"? In particular, he builds the Green's function using the parametrix method, which should be exactly what you are looking for.